# How to create an empty lstlisting?

Tags: listings

I am using `lstlisting` for code snippets. Currently, I am working on an exercise sheet, for which I need to create an empty `lstlisting`, which can later be filled out. Right now I create empty lines with a random symbol at the end, because only then Latex spans the list accordingly.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle, caption={}]





x
\end{lstlisting}
```

Is it possible to do this in a more professional way without this dummy symbol at the end? I'd like to have an empty list with a fixed number of lines. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit odd, but you can store an empty file and load it through `\lstinputlisting`, then the `lastline` parameter can be used to determine the number of lines that you want to show, here is the basic concept:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{emptyfile.my}

    
    
    
    
    
    

\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[lastline=5,showlines]{emptyfile.my}
\end{document}
```

[image]